# Updating component member doesn't refresh view in Angular

Tags: angular

I use [Angular](https://angular.io/) `9.17` and I have a button which executes a function to set a boolean value in the component. In my HTML template I have a `*ngIf` condition based on this boolean value, but the view does not update. Can anyone explain me why Angular doesn't detect this change?

```js
@Component({ selector: 'app', templateUrl: 'app.component.html' })
export class AppComponent {
    loggedIn: boolean = false;

    onLoginSubmit() { // bound to button
        this.loggedIn = true;
    }

    onLogoutSubmit() { // bound to button
        this.loggedIn = false;
    }
}
```

This is my template

```html
<span *ngIf="loggedIn">LoggedIn</span>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for everyone who started writing an answer. Restarting the `ng server` helped.